# Pass through bi-dimensional array with ng-repeat and $index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Having this input:

```
myArray = [
            {name: "name1", id: 1, parameters: ["first", "second"]},
            {name: "name2", id: 2, parameters: ["first"]},
            {name: "name3", id: 3, parameters: ["first", "second"]},
];
```

I want to put it on a table to look similar to this:

[image]

I tried to do it, the first two columns are correct but the last one doesn't appear:

```
<tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.name track by $index">
    <td>{{$ctrl.name[$index]}}</td>
    <td>{{$ctrl.id[$index]}}</td>
    <td><span ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.parameters[$index] track by $secondIndex">{{$ctrl.parameters[$index][$secondIndex]}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

The error message is

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use
>   'track by' expression to specify unique keys.

So probably two ng-repeats aren't the solution but it don't know how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need `track by $index` for the second `ng-repeat` as well, you can access the index of the parent loop with `$parent.$index` if you want

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should use `ng-repeat` on `myArray` and then show whatever you want.

And to show the `parameters` in the desired format you can use `row.parameters.toString().replace(',', ' ')`

Please check the working snipppet

Thanks

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
$scope.myArray = [
            {name: "name1", id: 1, parameters: ["first", "second"]},
            {name: "name2", id: 2, parameters: ["first"]},
            {name: "name3", id: 3, parameters: ["first", "second"]},
];

})
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Parameters</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in myArray">
    <td>{{row.name}}</td>
    <td>{{row.id}}</td>
    <td>{{ row.parameters.join(' ') }}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: parameters.toString().replace(',', ' ') = parameters.join(' ')

Comment: Oh yeah. that's a better option :) thanks. I'll update

Answer (score 1):

This should also work:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in myArray">
  <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  <td>{{item.id}}</td>
  <td>
    <span ng-repeat="subItem in item.parameters">{{subItem}}</span>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by [Aleksey Solovey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495123/aleksey-solovey) solved the problem:

```
<tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.name track by $index">
    <td>{{$ctrl.name[$index]}}</td>
    <td>{{$ctrl.id[$index]}}</td>
    <td><span ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.parameters[$index] track by $index">{{$ctrl.parameters[$parent.$index][$index]}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Don't use ng-repeat for this. It's a simple array of strings: $ctrl.parameters.join(' ')

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<tr ng-repeat="rows in myArray track by $index">
    <td>{{ rows.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ rows.id }}</td>
    <td><span ng-repeat="data in rows.parameters track by $index">{{ data+ " " }}</span></td>
</tr>
```